# How to undelete files after pushing to remote?

Tags: git

I accidentally deleted three and added the change to staging area and committed the changes and pushed.

Now I want to undelete these files and add few other changes to different files and push it remote. How to do it?

`git revert --no-commit` returns the following error.

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        MainUI/Common/KMessage/KMessage.mc
        MainUI/Common/KMessage/KMessage.rc
        MainUI/Common/KMessage/KMessage.res
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

fatal: revert failed

Comment: If they weren't tracked, you did not have a change to commit in the first place, as you can't ask git to delete files it isn't tracking. Can you try to explain with more detail what state you had, what you did and what you ended up with?

Comment: Before you do anything, back up your project folder. Then, perhaps try doing what it says (remove/move). My guess is you have those files in your project for some reason, but are currently on a commit where those files don't exist (anymore).

Answer (score 0):

try setting your head back by 2?

```
git reset HEAD~2
```

Should bring the files back. Given you pushed at least once before you pushed the delete commit.

Comment: assuming OP was tracking them